# sufficient and necessary conditions for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Give sufficient and necessary conditions such that the function $\frac{f(z)}{z^2-1}$ has a primitive in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{-1,1\}$ and in ${|z|>1}$.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me any idea of the solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A holomorphic function has an antiderivative on the domain $D$ if and only if $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every closed curve in $D$. What does that tell you about how $f$ must behave at $z = \pm 1$? (I assume you mean $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1, 1 \}$, rather than $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0, 1 \}$.)

Comment: I think f(1)=0 and f(-1)=0.

Comment: For the second question there are other possibilities too.

Comment: @user62138 You mean $f(-1)+f(1) = 0$, but yes.