# If a function is holomorphic in a certain domain, does it mean it necessarily has an antiderivative

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

Say I have a holomrphic function $f(z)$ in domain $D$, say $|z|>4$ and my function is not holomorphic for $|z|\le4$ - it has some poles there. Does it mean there is necessarily an antiderivative for $f(z)$?

I know I can use [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) and calculate all the residues inside $|z|\le4$ and check if their sum is zero. However what seemed more intuitive to me is to prove that since $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ for every $\mathbb{\gamma}$ contained in $D$, depends only on the start and end points, there exists an antiderivative for $f(z)$.

Is my prof correct? Can I conclude that in general, a holomorphic function in a domain $D$ not only has infinitely many derivatives in $D$, but it has also infinitely many antiderivatives there?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468056/42969

Answer (score 1):

No. If $f(z)=\frac1z$ (on $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|>4\}$), then $f$ has no antiderivative.

But if $f$ has the additional property that $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$ dpends only upon the initional and the end point of $\gamma$, then, yes, $f$ has an antiderivative. It does not follow, however, that such an antiderivative will have an antiderivative as well. Take $\frac1{z^2}$, for instance.

Comment: Come on, all this has been said many times before.

Comment: @MartinR The question “Does every holomorphic question have an antiderivative?” is a duplicate, yes. But that's not all that the OP has asked. There is also the extra assumption that the integral of the function along any path depends only upon the inicial and the end points and the question about whether then $f$ has antiderivative, and that antiderivative also has an antiderivative and so on. It may be a duplicate, but I have found no such question.

Comment: I didn't find the question marked as duplicate because I didn't know that antiderivative = primitive function.